# How do i keep the divs posted

Tags: php, mysql, database

My values are saving to the database, but how do i keep them on the page when I reload it?

Here's the code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Quotr.</h2>
 <div class="checkboxes"><?= !empty($_GET['x']) ? $_GET['x'] : '' ?>
   </div>

    </div>

  <?php $actual_quote = (isset($_GET['actual_quote']) ? $_GET['actual_quote'] : ''); ?>
  <div class="top-submit"><?php echo '&#8220;' . $actual_quote . '&#8221;'; ?>
  </div>
  <?php $poster = (isset($_GET['poster']) ? $_GET['poster'] : ''); ?>
 <div class="poster"><?php echo '-' . $poster; ?>
 <div class = "like">
 <a href = "javascript:countClicksLike();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "color:green;">Like</a>
 <p id = "like" style = "color:green;">0</p>
 </div>
<div class = "dislike">
<a href = "javascript:countClicks();" class = "btn btn-large" style = "float:right;   color:red;">Dislike</a>
 <p id = "dis" style = "color:red;">0</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- if there's an issue it may be this aswell-->
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'submissions');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
 $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected) {
die('Cannot use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO submissions (poster, actual_quote) VALUES ('$poster', '$actual_quote')";
if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error:' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

That's for recieving the code and storing it in the database.

I want it to stay on the webpage, it is saving and I know it is, but how do i keep it on the page?

Comment: You should be more specific, what are you trying to keep and where?  I don't see any form elements.  You also don't have any select statements to obtain the data from the database.

Comment: _“but how do i keep them on the page when I reload it?”_ – when you reload the complete page, you can not “keep” anything – you will have to _generate_ everything that you want to be on the page after it is reloaded again.

Comment: @CBroe, submitting content and other requests can be done without any changes to the user's page through ajax.  But I'm not sure what the OP wants.

Comment: @devon: Of course, I know that … I just explained what reloading the whole page means for what he/she wants.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to store your values in $_SESSION to retrieve them later on the page.

```
session_start();    
$_SESSION['x'] = $_GET['x'];
echo $_SESSION['x'];
```

[Session Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) are available on all pages for a particular user. You should unset variables after they serve their purpose as:

```
session_start();    
unset($_SESSION['x']);
```